# Why are Lua's iterators triples?

Tags: iterator, lua, language-design

Lua 5.1's reference manual states that an iterator

```
 for var_1, ···, var_n in explist do block end
```

is equivalent to the code:

```
 do
   local f, s, var = explist
   while true do
     local var_1, ···, var_n = f(s, var)
     var = var_1
     if var == nil then break end
     block
   end
 end
```

Why does Lua require the 'state' variable, *s*?

I would guess that it means that the iterator function does not need to carry any per-iterator state (see, e.g., the design of the *ipairs* iterator-yielding function), however it is quite straightforward to create closures on demand that carry this state, and the cost is pretty much once per iteration, the efficiency-based case is not that clear to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the triple design doesn't prevent you from using a closure, while the alternative approach prevents you from *not* using closures. Sometimes the external-state design is the simpler approach.

For instance, say that you're using a `for` loop to iterate which pages to display in the response to a RESTful query. With external-state-based loops, you can write a function that iterates pages based on a table representing the state-representational parameters of the query (which you construct from the URL once and reuse for several other functions). With triples, you can iterate with just those values without being forced to wrap it (and every other function like it) in a closure constructor.

Comment: Quite coincidentally, I noticed that the 5.2 manual has a section on "Stateless Iterators" that says that the purpose of the design is exactly this, to avoid the cost of creating new closures (p59).  So this is indeed the right answer.  I'm a bit surprised at this, per my reasoning in the question, but I guess you can contrive benchmarks where this cost dominates.

Comment: It's not just from a performance perspective. Sometimes creating a closure just makes the code more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Why not?  What's good about doing it some other way?  As they say at Microsoft, every idea to change something [starts out with minus 100 points](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx).

Comment: It's not the simpler semantics: the idea that the var element is the starting point and f tells you how to get to the next point from any point, is the way I have most often seen for representing iterators.  So I'm guessing that the pair semantics was considered alongside the triple semantics and suffered no -100 penalty.

Comment: Well the only person who can answer that definitively is probably the inventor of Lua.